# A Regra não está se aplicando aos elementos

Tags: css

Fiz uma base com um sistema de classes para determinada cor a um elemento. Mesmo colocando a regra ele não aceita.
Exemplo:

```
<span class="mc c0 s1">Olá Mundo :D</span>
```

No CSS está assim:

```
.mc .c0 {
    color: red;
}

.mc .s0 {
    font-style: italic;
}
```

E não esta aplicando a regra c0 e s0 juntas nem separadas. mesmo com o `!important` junto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como as classes fazem parte do mesmo elemento os seletores css devem ficar sem espaço:

```css
.mc.c0 {
color: red;
}

.mc.s1 {
font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<span class="mc c0 s1">Olá Mundo :D</span>
```

Porque assim, `.mc .c0` estás a dizer queres selecionar o elemento com a classe `c0` que seja filho, esteja contido, dentro elemento com a classe `mc`, ou seja referes-te a elementos diferentes.

Comment: Hm, funcionou mesmo. Por essa eu não esperava :)

Comment: hehe confesso que há uns anos, quando comecei também passei por esta duvida @sysWOW32 . Ainda bem que ajudei